# Objects gets overwritten in S3 while governance mode along with legal hold is enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm an absolute beginner in AWS and have been practising for 3 months from now.

Recently I was working on S3 and playing a bit with S3 object lock. So I enabled S3 object lock for a specific object with *governance mode along with legal hold*. Now when I tried to overwrite the object with the same file using the following CLI command:

```
aws s3 cp /Users/John/Desktop/112133.jpg s3://my-buck/112133.jpg
```

It succeeded interestingly and I checked in the console that the new file is uploaded with *Latest Version* on it. Now I read this in AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock-managing.html) that:

> Bypassing governance mode doesn't affect an object version's legal
> hold status. If an object version has a legal hold enabled, the legal
> hold remains in force and prevents requests to overwrite or delete the
> object version.

Now my question is how it get overwritten if this CLI command is used to overwrite a file? I tried also in the console to re uplaod the same file but it also worked.

Moreover I uploaded another file and enabled ojbect lock with *compliance mode* and it also get overwritten. But deletion doesn't work for both cases as expected.

Did I understand something wrong about the whole S3 ojbect lock thing? Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [Object Lock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock.html) documentation:

> Object Lock works only in versioned buckets, and retention periods and
> legal holds apply to individual object versions. When you lock an
> object version, Amazon S3 stores the lock information in the metadata
> for that object version. Placing a retention period or legal hold on
> an object protects only the version specified in the request. It
> doesn't prevent new versions of the object from being created.

Comment: Thanks. So basically what I was doing is, _uploading object into the bucket that has the same key name as an existing, protected object, Amazon S3 creates a new version of that object_. But how can I overwrite the file so that I can check _prevents requests to overwrite_ functionality?

Comment: Yes, writing to an existing object in a versioned bucket causes a new version of the object to be created. You can access individual versions of the object by specifying the version ID in your request.

Comment: Thanks again. But how to overwrite the file so that I can test _prevents requests to overwrite_ functionality? I also looked into _s3api_ clic commands but not find how to overwrite a file.

Comment: I'm not aware that you can overwrite a specific version of an object; all you can do is put a new object and that creates a new version. You can attempt to delete specific versions, however: use `aws s3api delete-object` with the `--version-id` option.

Comment: Yes. I used the delete command before and it works. But docs said overwrite object too should work but no api is available.

Comment: _Bypassing governance mode doesn't affect an object version's legal hold status. If an object version has a legal hold enabled, the legal hold remains in force and prevents requests to overwrite or delete the object version_. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock-managing.html

Comment: @Poles You probably already figured that out - in governance mode you can create new version of the object when you copy something over or you can create a delete mark when yo delete object. But hat version of the object which was locked in governance mode will stay there till the end of the period you set, unless you override governance mode options of the lock.